# Atmega2560 PWM on PH4

Tags: pwm, atmega2560, port-mapping

I am trying to convert the following code to output to pin 7 (PH4, OC4B) on an Arduino Mega. The code outputs to pin 6. This code is from a GitHub for the GRBL on the Mega "https://github.com/fra589/grbl-Mega-5X" out of the cpu_map.h It is clear that PH6 and PH7 are on the same PORTH but I just do not know what bits need changing to get GRBL to output on pin 7.Any help would be welcome.

```cpp
#elif defined (SPINDLE_PWM_ON_D6)

    // Set Timer up to use TIMER4C which is attached to Digital Pin 6 - Ramps Servo 2
    #define SPINDLE_PWM_MAX_VALUE     255.0 // Translates to about 1.9 kHz PWM frequency at 1/8 prescaler
    #ifndef SPINDLE_PWM_MIN_VALUE
      #define SPINDLE_PWM_MIN_VALUE   1   // Must be greater than zero.
    #endif
    #define SPINDLE_PWM_OFF_VALUE     0
    #define SPINDLE_PWM_RANGE         (SPINDLE_PWM_MAX_VALUE-SPINDLE_PWM_MIN_VALUE)

    //Control Digital Pin 6 which is Servo 2 signal pin on Ramps 1.4 board
    #define SPINDLE_TCCRA_REGISTER    TCCR4A
    #define SPINDLE_TCCRB_REGISTER    TCCR4B
    #define SPINDLE_OCR_REGISTER      OCR4A
    #define SPINDLE_COMB_BIT          COM4A1

    // 1/8 Prescaler, 16-bit Fast PWM mode
    #define SPINDLE_TCCRA_INIT_MASK (1<<WGM41)
    #define SPINDLE_TCCRB_INIT_MASK ((1<<WGM42) | (1<<WGM43) | (1<<CS41))
    #define SPINDLE_OCRA_REGISTER   ICR4 // 8-bit Fast PWM mode requires top reset value stored here.
    #define SPINDLE_OCRA_TOP_VALUE  0xFF // PWM counter reset value. Should be the same as PWM_MAX_VALUE in hex.

    // Define spindle output pins.
    #define SPINDLE_PWM_DDR   DDRH
    #define SPINDLE_PWM_PORT  PORTH
    #define SPINDLE_PWM_BIT   3 // MEGA2560 Digital Pin 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace pin 6 (PH3, OC4A) with pin 7 (PH4, OC4B). There are
three things you have to change. First, the output compare register,
which is OCR4A for pin OC4A and OCR4B for pin OC4B. Thus:

```
-#define SPINDLE_OCR_REGISTER      OCR4A
+#define SPINDLE_OCR_REGISTER      OCR4B
```

Then, the configuration bit that enables the output:

```
-#define SPINDLE_COMB_BIT          COM4A1
+#define SPINDLE_COMB_BIT          COM4B1
```

Last, the bit to set in the data direction register, which is 3 for PH3
and 4 for PH4:

```
-#define SPINDLE_PWM_BIT   3 // MEGA2560 Digital Pin 6
+#define SPINDLE_PWM_BIT   4 // MEGA2560 Digital Pin 7
```

Note: as in *diff -u* format, the prefix `-` means “remove this”, the
prefix `+` means “add this”.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I spent hours trying to figure out the datasheet.